# Complete AND Full Binary tree max and min indexes?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm not sure if i'm overthinking this, but I cannot think of the general case solution :(

[image]

Comment: Considering that a Binary Search Tree is a sorted tree where each left node is smaller than it's parent and each right node is bigger than its parent, it would be safe to say that the smallest value is the far left and the biggest value is the far right.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we store nodes having greater values in right subtree and smaller values in left subtree for any node, the node at `Bottom Right` corner will be having the maximum value and the node at `Bottom Left` corner will be having the minimum value.

So now you need to find the nodes. It is given that the tree is `Complete and Full BST` and also it is stored in Array so indexes are uniformly distributed over the nodes. So here we need to move `Top to Bottom` and `Left to Right` assigning index to nodes starting from `1` to `n` if there are `n` nodes.

So If we write indexes for given tree,

```
                            1
                         /     \
                        2       3
                      /   \   /   \
                     4     5 6     7
                    / \           ^^^-------------Largest value
                   8   9
Smallest value----^^^
```

So here a node having `8` index will be having the smallest value and a node having `7` index will be having the largest value.

So now the question is how to find it. So consider that we have a tree with level `l` then the index for largest value will be `2^level - 1` and smallest value will be at `2^level`th index.However the index we get here for largest value may give us a wrong answer if `total_nodes = 2^level-1`. So we need to calculate `level` for this in a different way by considering `total_nodes = n+1`.

```
int level = (int)(Math.ceil ( Math.log(n)/Math.log(2) ));    //For index of smallest value;
int smallest_index = (int) Math.pow (2,level);

level = (int)(Math.ceil ( Math.log(n+1)/Math.log(2) ));    //For index of largest value;
int largest_index = (int) Math.pow (2,level) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sanket's answer is basically right, but the way it is eventually stated makes me uncomfortable. Who's to say that the rounded(!) ratio of two rounded(!) logs won't round to *just* slightly higher than the intended integer? And then `ceil` will carry it all the way up. Maybe it works, but it would essentially be by accident, not by design.

It can also be stated "cleanly", without the need to think/worry about such things, in terms of bitwise arithmetic. Everything stays an integer, so it's easier to reason about.

The index of the lowest item is at the highest power of 2 present in `n`, so the highest set bit. In Java there is even a function for that: `Integer.highestOneBit`, or we could write it:

```
int highestOneBit(int x) {
    x |= x >> 16;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 1;
    return x ^ (x >>> 1);
}
```

And now we have

```
indexOfLowest = highestOneBit(n);
indexOfHighest = highestOneBit(n + 1) - 1;
```

This still assumes 1-based indexes (leaving index 0 unused), you can simply offset it all by 1 to make it 0-indexed.

Comment: This is the perfect way to get the level because for bigger values `Math.ceil()` or `Math.log()` may give inconsistent result so It is better to use bitwise operation which assures correct answer.